# Yii2 redirect causes blank page

Tags: php, redirect, yii2, shared-hosting

Is there any server/hosting setting that could cause simple redirect in Yii2 to not work?

For example:

```
function actionIndex(){
    return $this->redirect('other-page');
}
```

This code ends up with a blank page, no errors or messages are displayed(Error reporting is on), response code is 200 (although Yii2 debugger shows 302). Everything on my website works fine but as soon as code reaches any `->redirect()` it just end up with blank page.

This happens only on my clients shared hosting (on my local machine and development shared hosting everything works just fine).
Yii2 runtime logs does not show any errors, neither server logs that my hosting is giving me access to.

Comment: Just to be sure... what's the parameter you are calling? Is an array with a  `[route]`? A string with `URL`? Are you using alias in that string? And what's the new url you are being redirected to?

Comment: It does not matter. I have tried with string(http://google.com), array with a route, yii\helpers\Url::to(...) and everything ends up with a blank.
As for the url i am being redirected to I am not redirected anywhere acctually. When user enters example.com/admin he should be redirected to login page example.com/auth/login, but instead he stays at /admin with a blank page.

Comment: I see... for some reason your redirect isn't working (and since there is nothing being returned the page looks blank). Can you try use the native php redirect like  `header("Location: http://www.google.com")` and see if it works?

Comment: header("Location: http://www.google.com") alone works well, but that gave me idea. I debuged framework code and I found out this: `if(headers_sent()) {return;}`, when redirect is called it looks like that headers are already sent. None of `header("Location:...")` code is being executed hence no redirection. This did not occur on any of my other servers.

Comment: That's weird.. but can you check what's the header? Try a         `var_dump(getallheaders());` and `var_dump($this->_headers);` just after this if statement. (note that this will affect EVERY SINGLE page of this yii application, i won't recommend doing it if the application is already in use). If you have a header before, the `getallheaders` will show you. And the second one is just to be sure you are sending the new location header.

Comment: Ok, I went through framework files, line by line. When I commented out `if(headers_sent()) {return;}` YII finally threw an exception, only to let me find out that one of my config files had extra new line at the begining of the file. Something must have happened to that file when I was transfering it via ftp. This little bug gave me a real headache. Thanks @Clyff for giving me ideas for what to look for.

Comment: wow... always the little things... Congrats. And thank you for sharing the solution. Don't forget to, when you got some time, write your answer and accept it. It will make easier for other people find it. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that this was standard white page error: additional new blank line at the beginning of a php file.
I went through framework files, line by line. When I commented out `if(headers_sent()) {return;}` Yii finally threw an exception, only to let me find out that one of my config files had extra new line at the beginning of the file. Removing it fixed the problem.

Comment: To put some light why it worked on dev and not worked on production - your local server could have enabled [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering), so it will buffer this new line and app will be able to send headers. If output buffering is disabled, this blank line is immediately sent as request content and it is too late to send redirection header.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that no header sent before you send redirect response.

Also check your php file encoding, if you're using UTF-8 make sure that it's UTF-8 encode without BOM.