# Yii2 blank page on redirect

Tags: php, redirect, yii

I have a couple actions that I use redirects on but after transitioning to a new server all redirects now result in blank pages. I am not getting any errors in the logs and I already tried the suggestions in this question [YII2 redirect causes blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829969/yii2-redirect-causes-blank-page)

When I echo `var_dump(headers_sent())` it returns false. The Yii debug log displays the 405 status code also. Below is my action.

I've tried even using `header("Location: http://www.google.com")` and it also results in a blank page

```
public function actionDashboard()
    {

        if(strtotime(UserInfo::findOne(Yii::$app->user->Id)->active_until) < strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))){
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('warning', 'Please subscribe below.');
            return $this->redirect(['site/subscription'], 405);
        }

        $model = new Score();
        $deadlines = new EDeadlines();

        return $this->render('dashboard', [
            'deadlines' => $deadlines,
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
 public function actionSubscription()
    {

        Stripe::setApiKey(Yii::$app->params['stripe_sk']);

        $userInfo = UserInfo::findOne(Yii::$app->user->Id);

        $userInfo->customer_id != NULL ? $customer = Customer::retrieve($userInfo->customer_id) : $customer = NULL;

        $userPayments = StripeInvoice::find()
            ->where('customer_id=:customer_id', [':customer_id' => $userInfo['customer_id']])
            ->orderBy(['date' => SORT_DESC])
            ->all();

        $redeem_ch = NULL;

        $customer != NULL ? $account_balance = $customer->account_balance : $account_balance = 0;


        if($account_balance <= -1000 && $userInfo->refund_redeemed == 0):

            $redeem_ch = StripeInvoice::find()->where(['refunded' => 0, 'customer_id' => $userInfo->customer_id])->one();

            $userInfo->redeem_charge = $redeem_ch->charge_id;
            $userInfo->save();

        endif;

        return $this->render('subscription', [
            'userInfo' => $userInfo,
            'customer' => $customer,
            'account_balance' => $account_balance,
            'userPayments' => $userPayments,
            'referral_count' => UserInfo::find()->where(['referrer_code' => $userInfo->your_referral_code])->count(),
        ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using incorrect status code - `405` is not for redirections:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `405 Method Not Allowed` response status code indicates that the request method is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource.
>
> The server MUST generate an `Allow` header field in a 405 response containing a list of the target resource's currently supported methods.
>
> <sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405</sub>

You should remove this status from method call:

```
return $this->redirect(['site/subscription']);
```

Yii will use temporary redirection ([`302`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302)) which should be fine in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid array

```
return $this->redirect('site/subscription', 405);
```

and eventually use url::to

```
 use yii\helpers\Url;
 .....

 return $this->redirect(Url::to(['/site/subscription'])', 405);
```

Be sure you effectively need 405 (405 Method Not Allowed) instead of (302 Found = default)

Comment: even using `return $this->redirect(Url::to(['/site/subscription']), 405);` still results in a blank page. I do like that better so I'm keeping that in the code but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I've tried even using `header(...)` and it also results in a blank page

Comment: I already checked that, the subscription page never even gets requested

Comment: Ok I will add it tonight

Comment: I added the subscription action

Comment: I figured out the problem, when I remove the error code it works, now I need to figure out why the error code is causing this error now.

Comment: if I put any status code inside of the redirect it causes the blank page

Comment: Any status code? Did you try the default (302, as mentioned) - omitting the status code should be the same as using 302 - `public yii\web\Response redirect ($url, $statusCode = 302)`. The status codes have specific meanings and rules to both the client and server. Redirects should be 3xx. If need be, the page you are redirecting to can set a 4xx (or other) status. See: [Status Code Definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)